# How do I get git to stop changing newlines in my files?

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, github, egit

I'm using git/github with Eclipse/EGit on Windows. Something -- not sure if it's git or EGit -- is modifying my files by playing games with newlines.

Leaving aside the mystery of what a version control is doing modifying files by itself, how do I configure this software so it never, ever, changes my files?

Comment: Git doesn’t touch your newlines unless you’ve explicitly asked for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have many options depending on your OS:

http://help.github.com/line-endings/

The reason for the seemingly bizarre behavior is explained there.  Basically the code is being shared (git and github) but the OS may be different.  As different OS's treat linefeeds differently, something has to change...

Comment: Ok, this looks like it might be a working solution, but it doesn't address the problem of a version control system having the arrogance to change your code. For all its faults, svn does not have this problem.

Comment: Also, different OS's do not treat linefeeds differently. Different *applications* do. And if you use any modern programming languages, Java, whatever, they handle the CRLF problem just fine. Git should butt out.

Comment: ok, well I detect a bit of a rant here user237815 , but none the less I think this section also gives good details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems

Comment: i.e. "regular" programs such as editors "deal" with the OS difference by doing the conversion silently and as you desire git is *doing the same thing*.  Except that in this case the 'purpose' of git is to maintain code in a one format - it can't be Windows and Unix "at the same time" so it's unix and for windows the conversion happends when it's brought into a winodws system by git. Hope that help more.

Comment: For the record I think the best solution is for the whole community to come to the conclusion that CRLF no longer needs to be a thing. There is no benefit to it and it just complicates things. Please, all windows developers begin to switch to all LR line endings in your code and editors and in your global git config, this is the way forward.

Comment: Updated link to the accepted answer...  
[Configuring Git to handle line endings](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)

Answer (score 10):

```
git config --system core.autocrlf false
git config --system core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

Don't allow it to change anything or report problematic CR bytes at the end.